# Are questions about metrics on topic?

Tags: support, asking-questions

One of our supplier suffered a cyberattack and I'm writing a report on how we handled the situation. I plan to include some metrics I judge useful (eg: time taken to inform the relevant personnel). Since it's my first time doing so, I don't have a lot of experience and may miss some useful metrics. As a consequence, I would like to ask this community about useful metrics, things to take into account for this kind of analysis, ...
Would this be on topic here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds very open-ended, the way you've described the question. It sounds like a request for metrics that might apply.

Questions here have to have a hope of having a single acceptable answer. If you can phrase the question to do that, then it sounds fine.